# The term "context" in programming languages and how context is affected by loading and updation?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, grammar, context-free-grammar, formal-languages

What does the term context mean in context-free and context-sensitive languages? Can a variable have multiple contexts? If I need to store a particular value in a particular memory address how does does affect the context of the memory address? And if I want to update a variable how does the context of the variable change?

Comment: I think you are referring to different meanings of the same word. Without more context (no pun intended) about where you found these different uses, it's impossible to answer you. "context-free" and "context-sensitive" may refer to grammars, in the context of parsing. There are no memory addresses at parsing stage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A context-sensitive grammar, productions have the general form

```
aBc -> ab'c
```

where upper-case symbols are non-terminals and lower-case symbols are sequences of terminals and non-terminals.

In the above example, `a` and `b` would be the context of the non-terminal `B` and indicate that `B` may "expand" to `b'` only when surrounded by `a` and `c`.

In a context free grammar, the production might look like

```
B -> b'
```

i.e. `B` "expands" to `b'` regardless of whatever is around it, in other words, regardless of context.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int my_value = 0;

void print_value(void)
{
    printf("My value: %d\n", my_value);
}

int main(void)
{
    int my_value = 5;
    printf("My main value: %d\n", my_value);
    print_value();
    return 0;
}
```

This program will print:

```
My main value: 5
My Value: 0
```

The reason is that the variable `my_value` is linked to the one defined in the `main` function in the context of `main` and to the one defined as a global variable in the context of the `print_value` function. Most languages, like C, have context for their variable definitions allowing what is called `hiding` of variables: a variable defined inside of a block (the area between `{` and `}` signs) is not overriding previous definitions of the variable name, but rather "hides" them for the context of the block.

There are languages that are not context-sensitive where a name exists since the moment of definition and until the program exits. Updating a variable in these languages will update its value program-wide.